# Updating rows of a data.frame with the rows of another data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidytable

I want to update the rows of `data.frame`  `df1` with the rows of `data.frame`  `df2`. Any hint?

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    "V1" = LETTERS[1:4]
  , "V2" = 1:4
  , "V3" = 7:10
  )

df1
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  1  7
2  B  2  8
3  C  3  9
4  D  4 10


df2 <-
  data.frame(
      "V1" = c("A","D")
    , "V2" = c(5, 7)
    , "V3" = c(12, 15)
  )


df2
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  5 12
2  D  7 15
```

**Required Output**

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  5 12
2  B  2  8
3  C  3  9
4  D  7 15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use dplyr 1.0.0

```
rows_update(df1, df2)

Matching, by = "V1"
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  5 12
2  B  2  8
3  C  3  9
4  D  7 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1[df1$V1 %in% df2$V1,c('V2','V3')] <- df2[df2$V1 %in% df1$V1,c('V2','V3')]

  V1 V2 V3
1  A  5 12
2  B  2  8
3  C  3  9
4  D  7 15
```